# piped awk printf - find replace on a (awk) format modifier

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Im writing a bash script to send the output from "smartctl -a /dev/xx" over to whisper DB (part of graphite/carbon / grafana setup).

im using printf from awk to clean up the output before sending to whisper DB,  but i cant figure out a way to remove commas (from a number) in awk's %s printf output. (awk's format control letters)

the command is (i have cleaned up a bit for posting, full raw script is linked at bottom):

```
    smartctl -a /dev/${drivenvme} | \
    awk -v date="$(date +"%s")" '\
    /Power On Hours: /{pohours=$4} \
    END {
    printf "blah.server.POHhours %s %s \n", pohours, date;
    }'
    | /usr/bin/nc -w 3 172.17.69.42 2003
```

here is the relevant raw smartctl data piped into the above awk command:

```
root@freenas:~ # smartctl -a /dev/nvme2
Power On Hours:                     39,001
```

after awk command above runs, this is result / piped to netcat (/usr/bin/nc):

```
  `blah.server.POHhours 39,001 1591556405`
```

**So this above sends: POHhours 39,001**

**But i need it to send: POHhours 39001  (ie without the comma)**

**any ideas?**

I have though about instead of piping to netcat directly, save the awk output to a temp file ( ie "> /tmp/out.txt" ) and then:

while read /tmp/out.txt , sub "" for "," then > netcat -w 3 ....

But im more curious as to ideas on how to fix this without using a temp file. (thanks!)

here is the full raw bash script: https://pastebin.com/sTQEWcdj

and a sample of its output (ie what is sent to graphite / whisper DB): https://pastebin.com/0JBKkNTy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
END {
    printf "blah.server.POHhours %s %s \n", pohours, date
}
```

to:

```
END {
    gsub(/,/,"",pohours)
    printf "blah.server.POHhours %s %s \n", pohours, date
}
```

Comment: awesome!  works perfectly and now i can find/replace other vars as needed.  thanks so much for that great and FAST answer!